# esriPopup on close stop video play?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have MEDIA column in my attribute table contains video URLs (YouTube iframe & HTML5 video tag).

By Clicking on feature on map popup display and play the video.

I would like to stop video play when I click on close button of esriPopup window (InfoWindow).

I know the hide event of infoWindow, but How do I stop play video on close of the InfoWindow

```
 app.map.infoWindow.on('hide', function () {
var info = app.map.infoWindow.features[0].attributes.MEDIA;
});
```

Is there a way to stop video on close event of infoWindow?

Comment: Well I’m trying to show videos in my pop up with YouTube iframes but it doesn’t work. I see nothing, no console error no nothing. How you added the video to the pop up ?

Comment: Hi, right click on youtube video, copy embed code and paste in your attribute column. then in popup just add the column name.